# Spring/Hibernate data access concurrency problem

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I've been given full responsibility for a bunch of large projects that I didn't write myself and I am hoping for some advice here because these projects have issues that are keeping me up at night and much of this is new to me.

I've noticed that database queries through the ORM will sometimes not find an entity that had requested to be saved already, causing invalid state and crashes. The problem becomes more apparent with more concurrent threads that access the database through the ORM.

All the assistance I can get with troubleshooting would be much appreciated.

### Relevant dependencies

- Web framework: Spring MVC
- ORM: Hibernate
- DBMS: MySQL 5.6
- ehcache: 2.10.6
- Hibernate: 5.1.17.Final
- Hibernate validator: 5.4.3.Final
- MySQL connector: 5.1.48
- Spring: 4.3.29.RELEASE
- Spring integration: 4.3.23.RELEASE
- Spring security: 4.2.19.RELEASE

The web app runs under Tomcat 7 with Java 8 runtime.

We're behind on several dependencies and I want to tackle that another day.

### Troubleshooting

I read that `EntityManager` by itself is not thread-safe and that `@PersistenceContext` turns it into a proxy that allows thread-safe access to the underlying `EntityManager`. I can also see that it's some sort of proxy in the debugger. Now I don't know exactly how that works and whether the way we use it is *really* safe.

Despite that, I notice the following:

1. An incoming HTTP request causes an entity to be saved to the database through the ORM.
2. Shortly afterwards, another incoming HTTP request wants to find the same entity through the ORM.
3. Most of the time the entity is as expected found, but sometimes it is not found despite the fact that it should have been saved already.
4. If I try to find the entity on the same thread right after saving it then it's always found, but if I launch a new thread right after saving it then the entity may not be found in that thread unless I `Thread.sleep()` before the lookup.

I can see in the debugger that the same instance of `SomeService`, `SomeDaoImpl` and the `EntityManager` proxy in the example code below is reused for multiple incoming HTTP requests and handled by different threads.

Even though our own classes are stateless, there is apparently a problem with data access through the ORM.

### Greatly simplified pseudocode

```
interface Dao {
    Entity save(entity);
};

abstract class AbstractDao implements Dao {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em; // proxy

    @Override
    public Entity save(entity) {
        return em.persist(entity); // or this.em.merge(entity)
    }

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
}

abstract class AbstractUuidDao extends AbstractDao {
    public Entity findByUuid(uuid) {
        em = getEntityManager();
        query = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(...);
        // ...
        return em.createQuery(query).setParameter(..., uuid).getSingleResult();
    }
}

interface SomeDao extends Dao {};

@Repository
class SomeDaoImpl extends AbstractUuidDao implements SomeDao {}

@Service("someService")
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
class SomeService {
    @Autowired
    private SomeDao someDao;

    // the first HTTP request calls this
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    void createSomething() {
        uuid = "random uuid";
        someDao.save(new SomeEntity(uuid));
        someDao.findByUuid(uuid); // always returns non-null
    }

    // after createSomething() returns, the transaction is committed

    // two HTTP requests can call this simultaneously but they come in after createSomething() has returned, and therefore after the transaction has already been committed
    void getSomething(uuid) {
        // uuid is the same "random uuid"
        someDao.findByUuid(uuid); // can return either null or non-null
    }
}
```

I believe this is the persistence configuration:

```
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="model" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="custom class here" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction" />
            <entry key="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext" /> <!-- also tried "org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext" -->
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" /> <!-- also tried "false" -->
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" /> <!-- also tried "false" -->
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory" />
            <entry key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="8" />
            <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="10" />
            <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100" />
            <entry key="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm sorry for the lack of real code and details but it is difficult for me to provide a working example without making the example more complex than needed.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

### Update 1

I revised the example code in my original post to more correctly reflect the real use case, but it does not change much.

I can see that everything happens in the expected sequence, i.e. the transaction is committed and subsequent queries only happen afterwards.

I replaced our custom JPA dialect with `org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect` since it seems like the custom class is no longer needed because it was meant to add support for custom isolation levels. That did not help.

I have upgraded Hibernate from version 5.1.17 to version 5.2.18 and reimplemented an incompatible third party Hibernate user type that prevented the upgrade.

I have not seen a single failure since that upgrade but I will keep testing.

### Update 2

The issue does not seem to persist even with Hibernate version 5.2.0 either.

The following bugfix mentioned in the changelog looks very much related to my problem:

> [HHH-10649] - When 2LC enabled, flush session and then refresh entity cause dirty read in another session / transaction

If "2LC" means "second-level cache" then I have as mentioned before had the problem even after turning this off.

Comment: Depending on the isolation level that the code in `CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ` is running in it is of course totally possible that the transaction you start that code in is not yet committed therefore your changes are not visible to other transactions. If you want to read a value you have to make sure that the transaction creating that value has been committed before. I would start to find out where the second HTTP request is coming from and why it assumes that the value exists.

Comment: Thank you for the clue! That makes sense and I need to investigate that more thoroughly.

Comment: I do not quite believe it yet but the problem seems to no longer exist. I updated the original post with some details.

Comment: @Smutje mentioned a good detail. In addition, `save/persist` doesn't flush data directly to a database, therefore, changes will not be visible outside the transaction immediately, unless you explicitly call `commit()` in this transaction.

Comment: During my own investigation, I found that Spring uses AspectJ to intercept the function annotated with `@Transaction` and explicitly commits the transaction after that function returns in my case.

This is what I have observed after stepping through the code in the debugger which made this seeme like an impossible problem to me after checking Smutje's suggestion.

If that's not always the case then I must admit that I do not know.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the subsequent HTTP requests are coming in *after the Tx has been committed*? I had a situation where during a transaction I was notifying a client via WebSocket of a change to an object the client could subsequently re-request, and that client then made an HTTP call *whilst the transaction was still active* and thus the supposed changed object was not yet committed so the call received a "not found" response

Comment: Also, using a debugger slows down an application and so you might not see the same results as without a debugger, especially when it's about the time after exiting the method and the aspect-oriented code committing a transaction that sometimes might take milliseconds only

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned that because it would have made so much sense.

Client A sends a request to insert into the DB inside a tx.

After the `@Transaction`'d function returns (and the tx is committed which is verified by stepping over `commit()` and querying the DB manually), a notification is sent to Client B.

Client A's request completes and only then does it send a new request.

At the same time, Client B sends a request but only after receiving the notification.

This really happens in a controlled sequence verified with carefully placed breakpoints on the client and server.

Comment: But who is sending the notification to B and how?

Comment: The server who handles the incoming HTTP requests (and accesses the DB) sends notifications over a long-running HTTP connection (SSE).

Comment: To clarify, the server is not programmed to send notifications inside of a transaction or before the transaction is committed. I am however making an assumption that when `commit()` is called, it will block until the data is actually committed to the DB and no earlier. If that's not the case then that tiny time gap between `commit()` and when the data is truly committed could very well be the cause of the problem. I do not know that for sure though and I hope not.

Comment: It's hard to believe that the flaws are not in our own code but I have really tried hard to find them. I'll however stay open-minded for the time being just in case.

Comment: In my case it was sufficient to send the notification in a (new) second transaction to make sure that the first transaction was committed - both in a JEE and a Spring application. But without further details on how the notification is produced this is just a speculation because you haven’t included the code that calls SomeService.